# How to open a contact card in Android by ID

Tags: android, contacts

Is it possible to open an android contact card by contact's ID? It works with the phone-number. Here is an example, if I use

```
Intent i = new Intent();
i.setAction(ContactsContract.Intents.SHOW_OR_CREATE_CONTACT);
i.setData(Uri.fromParts("tel", "123456", null)); //<---- Change here from Phone to IDcontext.startActivity(i);
```

But I want to open this contact card by ID, for example if the phone-number from the contact would change.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

use ACTION_VIEW and either build a contact URI using the contact ID or use the contact lookup URI if you already have it (preferred).

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    Uri uri = Uri.withAppendedPath(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, String.valueOf(contactID));
    intent.setData(uri);
context.startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: Just as a side note: It's discouraged to pick contacts by `id`, because it's not guaranteed that it won't change. In fact the chances are very high that the id *WILL* change. You should use jhominal's solution and pick it up with LOOKUP_URI, because lookup key always stays same. Background: The `ID` can be changed during synchronizations, so don't depend on it or your app may break at any time in future during or after a contact list synchronization

Comment: Wow, so obviously missed the meaning of "id"... thank you Tseng, I'll change it in my code and remember for the next time :)

Comment: Yea, had to go through that thing when I ported one of my Apps from 1.6 to 2.x as the whole Contact thing was changed and old stuff broke

Comment: Hy i need to call Intent.ACTION_PICK because i need to select number and fetch from my application but its not working..any idea than please suggest me how its possible ?

Answer (score 6):

You would use the following URI:

```
Uri.Builder newUriBuilder = ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_LOOKUP_URI.buildUpon();
newUriBuilder.appendPath("/").appendPath(theContactKey)
i.setData(newUriBuilder.build());
```

You will find more details about how this URI works by looking at the [API documentation for CONTENT_LOOKUP_URI](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.Contacts.html#CONTENT_LOOKUP_URI).

Comment: Ok, thank you jhominal for pointing in the right direction, but your answer was not completely right. Here is the right solution: Uri look = Uri.withAppendedPath(Contacts.CONTENT_LOOKUP_URI, hereTheLookupKey); Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW); i.setData(look);

Comment: isn't using this URI better: Contacts.getLookupUri(contactId, lookupKey) ?

Answer (score 4):

I was trying to open a contact card using the listed here methods, but somehow the contacts activity was closing immediately after it was opening.

it seemed that the contact activity didn't accept my old content uri.

I resolved this problem using the `getLookupUri (long contactId, String lookupKey)` method of `ContactsContract.Contacts` class for obtaining the right content uri [https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.Contacts.html#getLookupUri(long, java.lang.String)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.Contacts.html#getLookupUri(long,%20java.lang.String))

So the code for opening a contact card becomes:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
String lookupKey = phonesCursor.getString(phonesCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(ContactsContract.PhoneLookup.LOOKUP_KEY));
long contactId = phonesCursor.getLong(phonesCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(ContactsContract.PhoneLookup._ID));
Uri uri = ContactsContract.Contacts.getLookupUri(contactId, lookupKey);
intent.setData(uri);
startActivity(intent);
```