# Open contact intent DISPLAY_NAME

Tags: java, android, mysql, database, sqlite

```
    String exactname = "Joe Blogs"
```

I've searched high and low of a way to directly open the contact using [DISPLAY_NAME](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.ContactsColumns.html#DISPLAY_NAME) not the [_ID](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.RawContactsColumns.html#CONTACT_ID) of the contact.

EDIT: Joe Blogs is definitely a unique entry.

From [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4275598/1256219)

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    Uri uri = Uri.withAppendedPath(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, String.valueOf(contactID));
    intent.setData(uri);
    context.startActivity(intent);
```

Do I have to query the ID of Joe Blogs before I can open his contact with an intent similar to the above? Or have I (hopefully) missed something?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What if you have two contacts with same name.That's why android needs id.because id are unique.

Comment: I meant to add in the question that Joe Blogs is definitely unique.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you need to query your database with something like,

```
Cursor cur = getContentResolver().query(CONTENT_URI, null, DISPLAY_NAME + "=?", new String[] { "Joe Blogs" }, null);
```

Then retrieve the row returned by the `Cursor` with,

```
if (!cur.moveToFirst()) {
    // Then the cursor isn't empty. Get the contact's id.
    contactId = cur.getInt(cur.getColumnIndex(CONTACT_ID));
}
```

This will return the contact id associated with the first record in the `Cursor`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. In your example could I replace new String[] { "Joe Blogs" } with 'exactname' - I'm about to test for myself. Also, is there no direct look-up method such as getID(exactname) for example? Thanks.

Comment: No, and the reason why there is no method like that is because you are gathering data from a *database*, not a *class*. This is an important concept to understand.