# Go to certain contact in contacts via intent

Tags: android, android-intent, uri, contacts

I have contact uri´s in my app and I want to open a certain contact in the android contacts app via intent.

```
Intent intent= new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,  ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI);
                context.startActivity(intent);
```

This piece of code opens the contacts, but I don´t know how to go to a contact. How does it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify the contact with a contact lookupKey

Comment: thank you, found another thread now with this keyword http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4275167/how-to-open-a-contact-card-in-android-by-id sould work for me, I´ll test it soon