# Open contact in kotlin in the contacts app

Tags: android, kotlin

I am new to kotlin, and I am using flutter and writing native code in kotlin to try and open a contact.
At the moment I am using this code

`var intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_DEFAULT, ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI); startActivityForResult(intent, 1);`  
This opens contacts, but I am trying to open a specific contact.

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4275167/how-to-open-a-contact-card-in-android-by-id) maybe can help?

Comment: Thank you I will check when I'm at my computer. 